# Mongodb find distinct count with condition

Tags: mongodb

How to have to select in mongodb.

```
Select room(distinct), count(where read =1)
from chat
where from = "1" or to ="1"
```

This is my json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595da6052008fc2213db32f6"),
    "room" : "1_40",
    "from" : "1",
    "to" : "40",
    "user_name" : "Tran Cot",
    "mes" : "hgfd",
    "time" : 1499309573832,
    "read" : 1
}
```

Comment: Most of that is not a problem. The "from" and "to" becomes a real problem though because all your data is represented as "strings". So you cannot really do numeric comparisons on "strings". You really should fix your data first and make numeric values of the things that should be numeric.

Comment: Im sorry that was string to string comparisons update my code

Comment: You misunderstand. Strings will not work. Fix your data. That should be simple enough to not misunderstand.

Comment: OK just pretend my json was number 1 instead of string "1". How? thanx

Comment: it not the problem with from and to coz I can do query like below.
db.chat.distinct("room",{$or:[{from:"41"},{to:"41"}]})
return value
[ "1_41", "40_41" ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want total read messages for each room..

use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

### updated

```
db.chat.aggregate([
  { $match: { $or: [{ from: "41" }, { to: "41" }] } }, 
  { $group: { 
    _id: "$room", 
    count: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: { if: $eq: ["$read", false], then: 1, else: 0 }
      }
    }
  }}
]);
```

Comment: Got it: 
db.chat.aggregate([
{ $match : { $or:[{ from: "1"}, {to: "1"}] } },
{ $group: { _id: "$room", count: { $sum: {$cond : { if: { $eq: ["$read", false]}, then: 1, else: 0}} } } }
])